Align point clouds with open3d, and color by depth
I'm trying to align 5 point clouds with open3d, this point clouds are 5 view point of a face.






For the alignment i used this tutorial as a reference.
How i can align the 5 point clouds and how i can set a color based by depth?

Also, if there is a manual method to do this, I would use it.
